# Copied the Internal CSS to an External CSS, some items dont look the same

Tags: css

I took my internal CSS and did a copy paste to an external CSS document and some of the formatting has gone away. I did not change anything from the internal to external and I know it is working because some of the formatting is working. Has anyone ran across this before and might have a answer to why this might happen?

Comment: what formatting? the formatting of the css directives themselves, or the rendering of the page(s) that the css applies to?

Comment: You'd need to post an example so we can see, but I'd suspect that you're running into an issue where your CSS selectors aren't specific enough, so are getting overwritten.

Comment: you didn't copy it well, or the are some properties overwriting others

Comment: Think I messed up on my 1st response so. ugg dont press enter to go to a new line. I copied like: <style>

body {
background-color:#404040;
text-align:center;
}
  
#container {
background-color:#404040;
width:900px;

} to a external style sheet, but the document is not centered anymore, and my nav buttons are missing. Some of the formatting is there, but alot is missing. If I move it back inside the xhtml document it works fine.

Comment: Going to need to see an example

Comment: I removed the <style> </style>, same thing is going on. I will fiddle around with it. I did not apply any inline styles but I will check again for anything that would override it. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: `<style>` and `</style>` definitely should not be present in the external style to start. It should have only plain CSS and no HTML tags whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Inline style override internal styles, internal styles override external styles. Most probably your styles are being overwritten...

I see the problem now, from the comment, Remove `<style>` and `</style>` from external css.
`<style>` attribute tells the browser that what follows next is style, but when using external stylesheets you do not need to put the `<style>` tag as you already tell the browser what it is when you import the file by using `type` and `rel` attributes.